# Webview client file openfilechooser returns blank white screen

Tags: android, eclipse, webview, android-webview

There are a few questions on the issue of making a openfilechooser work on Android and I have applied the recommended solutions.

My issue is not that its not working on 4.4 yet as I will tackle that next, but I just need it to work on my test device 4.2.2 (Note8) but its returning a blank white screen once the image is selected.

I have rechecked my code and reviewed many many solutions and they all are giving the same solution, but I just cant seem to find whats wrong.

Heres my code:

```
 private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;  
 private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;  

 @Override  
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  
                                    Intent intent) {  
  if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)  
  {  
   if (null == mUploadMessage) return;  
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null  
                    : intent.getData();  
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);  
            mUploadMessage = null;  
  }
  }     

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_team_page);
    mHandler = new Handler();




getUser = ((MyData)getApplicationContext());


TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    Date now = new Date();
    int offsetFromUtc = tz.getOffset(now.getTime()) / 3600000;
    m2tTimeZoneIs = Integer.toString(offsetFromUtc);

userCredentials = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("me2team", MODE_PRIVATE);

isShowingDesktop = false;

m2tUser = getUser.getCredentialsUser();
m2tPswd = getUser.getCredentialsPwd();
isPremiumUser = getUser.getPremiumUser();

tempWebURL = getResources().getString(R.string.teamURLMobile);
webURL = tempWebURL + "?username=" + m2tUser + "&password=" + m2tPswd + "&mobile=1&offSetHours=" + m2tTimeZoneIs;

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.teamWebView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false); //as per Janet's request
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.setInitialScale(70);

    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    webView.setAlpha(255);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

      @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {  

          mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
          Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
          i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
          i.setType("image/*");  
          TeamPage.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);  

         }

      // For Android 3.0+
      @SuppressWarnings("unused")

         public void openFileChooser( ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType ) {
         mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
         Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
         i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
         i.setType("*/*");
         TeamPage.this.startActivityForResult(
         Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
         FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
         }

      //For Android 4.1

         @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
             mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
             Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
             i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
             i.setType("image/*");  
             TeamPage.this.startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( i, "File Chooser" ), TeamPage.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );

         }

      public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
      {
          activity.setTitle("Loading...");
          activity.setProgress(progress * 100);             
          if(progress == 100)
          {
              activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

          }                  
      }             
  });

  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

I checked with the server chap and he is not seeing any errors on his side when I select the file, so its like it just stops doing anything.  Thing is if I log out of the web site and then go log back in, I still get the same white screen?  Its not till I restart the app that it returns to the web page (remembers login details and auto logs in).

And ideas?

Comment: Is onActivitResult called with a URI and passed back to WebView via the uploadMessage? Or are you not seeing that getting called?

Comment: (Additionally, this is not supported at all on Android 4.4). `openFileChooser` is a hidden API that should technically not be being used by apps and it was removed in KitKat.

Comment: Thanks Ksasq, I will look at onActivityResult and see whats what.  So what do we do now with Kitkat as yea my Galaxy5 wont work at all as its KitKat but the Note8 does work till I hit the issue above.  For now the owner of the app has pulled the feature till I sort it out for all versions of Android.

Comment: I don't think there is a workaround for KitKat devices, i'm afraid.

Comment: yea I know.  This is going to be a fix that will take a bit of time and lots of testing.  And no idea yet on what to do with Kitkat.